# how is System.in an inputstream object?

Tags: java

May be this is basic question but i just want to clear my doubt.

System class is present in java.lang.Object(java.lang.System) and has three fields in,out and err.
Then how is System.in an Inputstream object where Inputstream is from java.lang.Object java.io.Inputstream.

Comment: `System.in` is a field of `System` called `in` which is defined as an `InputStream` There is no reason a field cannot be any allowed type.

Comment: Imagine I had a  `String`... It has a `length` field which is an integer. The type of the class and the type of the things inside it do _not_ need to match.

Comment: Just for the record: please consider if one of the answers was helpful to you; and if so: consider accepting it!

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you are confusing yourself. Lets step back.

The class **[java.lang.System](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html)** has several **static** fields, one of them is called [in](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#in).

That in is an Object (because everything except primitive types is an descendent of java.lang.Object) of type [InputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html).

In that sense, you want probably look into [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html) to figure what all those terms actually *mean*.

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the implementation of the `System` class, you'll find this field `public final static InputStream in = nullInputStream();`.

So it's just a static initialized `InputStream` object which you can access with `System.in`. `System.out` and `System.err` are analogous.

Comment: Thanks brute for answering. we write public final static String name = "xxx"; here String object is present in Object class which is super class so we can use its methods. when we declare static Inputstream in system class which extends object, Inputstream is not present in Object class so my doubt is how can we declare it as InputStream. Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @NarayanaDasari Your question and your comment are difficult to understand. "String object is present in Object" what does that mean? "Inputstream is not present in Object class". what does that mean? What you say doesn't make any sense in Java. Neither "String object" nor "Inputstream" "are present in" "Object".

Comment: Thank you @Erwin Bolwidt..You cleared my doubt..I'm beginner in java.